# How many time to refresh the repository in the GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I pushed a new repository, let's say named test in the servoz organisation.

As a first use of the API, I want a global view of this repository and I type in a shell:

```
% curl https://api.github.com/repos/servoz/test # linux OS
```

I observe in the return:

```
"size": 0,
```

So I deduce that the repository is not yet updated via the API, right ?

Is it done when it is possible (:-) or what is the rule (after 1 min, 5 mins, etc .. other way to do ?)

Comment: Wasn't me, but I'd guess it was because they thought this was a question for GitHub's support directly. Like you said the answer isn't evident from their documentation so we're not going to know any more than you.

Comment: I understand and agree with you, @Rup. That's why I first asked the question directly on the GitHub community forum. Because, generally I find a very good support on stackoverflow, I also asked there ! Anyway, I had no more answer in the GitHub community forum..... https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/How-many-time-to-refresh-the-repository-in-the-GitHub-API/m-p/23155#M1625

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the delay between a push on Github and the update of the data via the GitHub's API.
I observed that the update takes place exactly one hour after the push.

I haven't done any other pushes in the meantime between the push and push+1h. What would be the result if other pushes are made in the interval?

I would do other tests later, but the answer to my first question, seems to be: 1 hour.

Comment: I seem to be having a similar problem. Notifications are not getting updated in the API. I takes a while.