# How long does it take for GitHub api to refresh the data after being changed in github

Tags: github, next.js, fetch, github-api

I'm fetching data from github api to my site.
I was trying to use topics="tailwindcss" as a query. It was showing all the repo which have tailwindcss as topic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGpat.png)
now I add tailwindcss as a topic in pomodoro repo.
and it is showing in postman api call

```
{
        "id": 693490688,
        "node_id": "R_kgDOKVXUAA",
        "name": "pomodoro",
        "full_name": "ARITRA69/pomodoro",
        "private": false,
        "owner": {
            ...
        },
        "html_url": "https://github.com/ARITRA69/pomodoro",
        "description": null,
        ...
        "topics": [
            "featured",
            "tailwindcss"
        ],
        "visibility": "public",
        ...
    },
```

as you can see.
But the pomodoro is not showing in my api call

**codes:**

api call:

```
const GITHUB_TOKEN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN;

export default async function getRepos() {
try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/aritra69/repos",
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
            },
        }
    );
const repos = await response.json();

    const filteredRepos = Array.isArray(repos)
      ? repos.filter(
          (repo) =>
            repo.topics &&
            repo.topics.length > 0 &&
            repo.topics.includes("tailwindcss")
        )
      : [];
    return filteredRepos;

} catch (error) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch users");
  }
}
```

display data:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import getRepos from "@/lib/getRepos";
import ProjectCard from "@/components/ProjectCard";

const Projects = async () => {
  const repos = await getRepos();

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen w-11/12 xl:w-[55%] mx-auto mt-36 space-y-36">
      <Link
        href="/"
        className="text-foreground/50 group hover:text-foreground/80 transition-all duration-500 flex items-center gap-2"
      >
        <span className="group-hover:-translate-x-2 transition-all duration-500">
          ←
        </span>
        <span>Go Back</span>
      </Link>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10 justify-items-center pb-36">
        {repos.map((repo) => (
          <ProjectCard
            key={repo.id}
            name={repo.name}
            href={repo.html_url}
            description={repo.description}
            language={repo.language}
            topics={repo.topics}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Project Card:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  key: number;
  name: string;
  href: string;
  description: string;
  language: string;
  topics: [string];
};

const ProjectCard = ({ name, href, description, language, topics }: Props) => {
  function convertAndUppercase(name: string) {
    return name
      .replace(/-/g, " ")
      .split(" ")
      .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
      .join(" ");
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full p-5 bg-neutral-900 rounded-xl flex flex-col justify-between gap-y-10">
      <Link href={`/projects/${name}`} className="flex flex-col">
        <h1 className="text-base md:text-lg hover:text-foreground/70 transition-all duration-500 ease-in-out">
          {convertAndUppercase(name)}
        </h1>
        <p className="text-foreground/50 text-xs md:text-sm">{description}</p>
      </Link>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between gap-10">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
          {language && (
            <>
              <div className="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-600"></div>
              <p className="text-xs">{language}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="flex gap-1 text-xs text-foreground/60 flex-wrap">
          {topics.map((topic, i) => (
            <p
              key={i}
              className="py-1 px-2 rounded-full bg-background/50 whitespace-nowrap"
            >
              #{topic}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectCard;
```

I was thinking that the api may take long time to update. But if that's the case then it will not be updated in the postman

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55973163/17627866), it takes around 1 hour. For a more accurate answer, you will have to either measure the time delay yourself or contact Github for details.

Comment: thank you very much. I found another thing. I was fetching data at server side and next 14 cashes the fetched data and don't fetch even after reloading. I we fetched with axios in client side the data will change immediately. 
And for server side we can use revalidate={time after it clears the caches(in sec)}

Comment: For your new question, you will have to post a new question on Stack Overflow as it is not related to the current one. A quick answer is that you might have exceeded the [API limit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28).

Answer (score 0):

There is no official statement from Github yet on the time it takes for the API to serve the latest information. This might change in the future so make sure to monitor their [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest).

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55973163/17627866) by someone who measured the time delay, the answer is **around 1 hour**. You could measure this delay yourself to have a more accurate answer because this delay probably fluctuates:

1. Make a change to your repository and start a timer.
2. Write a script to send a request using Github API.
3. Check if your change has propagated. If yes, stop timer else wait 5 mins and send request again.